# Django Error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BuildsTable'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save an object to the database but I get the error:

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BuildsTable'`

I have a separate script that is supposed to populate my database with many names of motherboards, and prices.

My models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class BuildsTable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    moboListing = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

My database populating file is called fillDB.py:

```
import sys
import os


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.path.append('/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/computerbuilder/')
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "computerbuilder.settings")

    from builds.models import BuildsTable

    mobo = BuildsTable.objects.all()
    print mobo

moboDB = open("db.txt", "r")
lines = moboDB.read().split('\",')
print lines

def main():
    global lines
    global BuildsTable

    for item in lines:
        try:
            mobo = BuildsTable(moboListing="%s" % item[0])
        except BuildsTable.DoesNotExist:
            mobo = 1
        try:
            price_local = BuildsTable(moboListing="%s" % item[1])
        except BuildsTable.DoesNotExist:
            price_local = 1
        """    
        if(BuildsTable.objects.filter(
            moboListing = mobo, price = price_local).exists() == False):
        """
        mydb = BuildsTable(moboListing = mobo, price = price_local)

        print mydb
        mydb.save()

main()
```

How can I populate my database with a list of motherboards?

My full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fillDB.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "fillDB.py", line 38, in main
    mydb.save()
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1511, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 898, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 856, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 350, in get_db_prep
_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 342, in get_db_prep
_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/waleedasif322/Documents/cb/computerbuilder_masterrepo/cbenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1073, in get_prep_v
alue
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BuildsTable'
```

Comment: thanks for checking this out, I edited the question.

Comment: Just change `mydb = BuildsTable(moboListing = mobo, price = price_local)` to `mydb = BuildsTable.objects.create(moboListing = mobo, price = price_local)`

Comment: thanks, I tried that, but got a similar error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `mydb` cannot be saved, because you're setting a `BuildsTable` object to an integer field. Consider this:

```
try:
    price_local = BuildsTable(moboListing="%s" % item[1])
except BuildsTable.DoesNotExist:
    price_local = 1
# ...
mydb = BuildsTable(moboListing = mobo, price = price_local)
```

There you go, setting `price` to a `BuildsTable` instead of an integer. This won't work.

Btw your other try-catch is suspicious too, where you set `mobo = BuildsTable(moboListing="%s" % item[0])`, and then later use `mobo` as the value of `moboListing`.

Finally, you know that the whole script is a dirty hack. The right way to manipulate Django from scripts is to write [custom Django admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). It's really not harder, and you'll get more robust and reliable solutions.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so basically this is a no go, and I should rewrite the code using django-admin commands?

Comment: Yes. It won't be a big effort, basically you just have to wrap your code inside Django's structures. It will eliminate some strange behavior you might get otherwise sometimes, so it's good to adopt the technique early.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to work on that and post back here with results. New to python.