# TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Model Instance'

Tags: python, django, django-models, populate

Here's my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
   location_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.location_name

class Menu(models.Model):
   location = models.ManyToManyField(Location)
   restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   dish_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   VNV_tag = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   quantity = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='FULL')
   price = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=0)
   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.restaurant_name
```

I am trying to populate my database from an excel file using `xlrd` python module.
Here's my **populate_db.py** script:

```
import os
import xlrd
from menusearch.models import Menu, Location
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'midnitepro.settings')
import django
django.setup()

def populate():
    book = xlrd.open_workbook('/Users/Sahil/Desktop/MNFP1.xlsx')
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    count1 = 0
    while count1<sheet.nrows:
        value_list = []
        count2 = 0
        while count2<sheet.ncols:
            value_list.append(sheet.row_values(count1, start_colx=count2, end_colx=count2+1))
            count2 +=1
        add_menuitem(value_list)
        count1 += 1

def add_menuitem(value_list):
    split_query = []
    m = Menu.objects.create()
    value_list = [str(x[0]).encode('utf-8') for x in value_list if x]

    m.restaurant_name = (value_list[0])
    m.dish_category = (value_list[1])
    m.dish_name = (value_list[2])
    m.VNV_tag = (value_list[3])
    m.quantity = (value_list[4])
    m.price = (value_list[5])
    # m.location.add(int(value_list[6]))

    split_query = (value_list[6]).split(",")
    for sq in split_query:
        l = Location.objects.get_or_create(location_name=sq)
        try:
            m.location.add(l)
        except ValueError:
            print "Problem Adding Location to Menu."

    m.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting population script..."
    from menusearch.models import Menu, Location
    populate()
```

Now when I run the populate_db.py script, the output on the terminal reads: "**Problem Adding Location to Menu.**". I see that the problem exists here in the populate_db script: **m.location.add(l)**
But this queryset is in line with the syntax given here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

After removing the try/except, my traceback reads:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Location'
```

Please explain what is happening here.
And how to properly add a a value to the **ManyToManyField** via a queryset.

Possible duplicate: [Django Error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BuildsTable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23229108/django-error-typeerror-int-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-build?rq=1)
But I would still like to know the answer in my case as I'm using a ManyToManyField.

Full traceback:

```
l= (<Location: Indiranagar>, False)

Inside Loop - sq=  Indiranagar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_db.py", line 62, in <module>
populate()
  File "populate_db.py", line 23, in populate
add_menuitem(value_list)
  File "populate_db.py", line 50, in add_menuitem
m.location.add(l)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 973, in add
self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1079, in _add_items
'%s__in' % target_field_name: new_ids,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in filter
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 697, in _filter_or_exclude
clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1304, in add_q
clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1332, in _add_q
allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1194, in build_filter
lookups, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1745, in get_lookup_constraint
root_constraint.add(lookup_class(targets[0].get_col(alias, sources[0]), value), AND)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 96, in __init__
self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 134, in get_prep_lookup
return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 729, in get_prep_lookup
return [self.get_prep_value(v) for v in value]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 985, in get_prep_value
return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Location'.
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback. If you removed the try/except here, I would expect to see an error about a tuple, because `get_or_create` returns `(instance, created)`.

Comment: Yes totally, Updated.

Comment: **l= (<Location: Indiranagar>, False)**

This is the output from *get_or_create*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a value to a ManyToManyField, you need to add the objects by passing them as arguments.

```
add(obj1, obj2, obj3, ...)
```

This will add the specified objects to the related object set.

You can call the `add()` like below:

```
menu_object.location.add(loc_obj1, loc_obj2, ...)
```

**In your case, you need to do:**

```
l = Location.objects.get_or_create(location_name=sq)[0]
```

You need to access the `instance` by index `0` as `get_or_create` returns a tuple `(instance, created)`. Then pass this `instance` to the `add()` method.

**Note:**
Using `add()` with a many-to-many relationship will not call any `.save()`  for each object, but rather create the relationships using `.bulk_create()`.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing. Does Not Work.

Comment: You are  doing `m.location.add(int(value_list[6]))`. Whats `value_list[6]`? Is it the location object

Comment: That statement is a comment. That's not what I'm doing.
On the other hand I am trying this: `m.location.add(l)`
where `l = Location.objects.get_or_create(location_name=sq)`

Comment: Try this: `l = Location.objects.get_or_create(location_name=sq)[0]`

Comment: It worked Rahul. Pls edit in the Main answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4):

I understand that Rahul Gupta has answered this already. But on a more theoretical level I think this is what happened when you use `get_or_create` here:

```
l = Location.objects.get_or_create(location_name=sq)
```

It returns a Tuple, and hence you have to call it's first element by modifying it to:

```
l = Location.objects.get_or_create(location_name=sq)[0]
```

Which returns only the index element of the tuple/dictionary!

Comment: Yup. I agree. This is precisely what is happening.