# Django: Saving a user instance -- failing both ways

Tags: python, django, instance

I have a model set up as so:

```
class ShiftLog(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    project = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    staff_member = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

When I try to save a ModelForm, I get this error:

```
Cannot assign "[<User: stephen>]": "ShiftLog.staff_member" must be a "User" instance.
```

So in the views.py, I tried this instead (changing from the normal form handling):

```
@login_required
def shiftlog_form(request):
    login = request.user.last_login
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ShiftLogForm(request.POST.copy())
        form.data['staff_member'] = User.objects.get(id=form.data['staff_member'])
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render_to_response('shiftlog_form.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            print('form is not valid')

    else:
        form = ShiftLogForm()
        return render_to_response('shiftlog_form.html',
                                  {'form': form},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And then I get this error:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'User'
```

Starting to feel a little bit like a die if you do, die if you don't situation. Any ideas? Also for reference, this is running on Python 2.7, Django 1.4.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I got exactly the same error `int() argument must be a string or a number` with the `django.contrib.auth.models` in my project, it seems like a bug related to `django.db.models.Model`. Check the results of `User.objects.get` in your `view.py`. It's very likely that something nontrivial is passed to `ShiftLogForm`.

Comment: Also try `form.data[...]=User.objects.get(...)[0]`, as suggested in another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348012/typeerror-int-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-model-instance)